# Gatsby, Gsap - gsap animations not working after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gsap

I'm creating website using gatsby and gsap.
All animations are working while development, but not on production version.

I'm animating a svg image, using Gsap V3.

Where could be a problem?

Thanks for feedback!

```
const HeaderComponent = () => {

  const animWrapper = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    const [elements] = animWrapper.current.children

    const what = elements.getElementById('What')
    const ever = elements.getElementById('Ever')
    const button = document.getElementById('header-button')
    const icon = document.getElementById('header-icon')

    const whatChildrens = what.children
    const everChildrens = ever.children
    const allChildrens = [...whatChildrens, ...everChildrens]

    gsap.set([...allChildrens, button], { autoAlpha: 0 })

    const timeLine = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: 'power3.inOut' } })

    timeLine
      .to(whatChildrens, { autoAlpha: 1, duration: 0.75 })
      .to(everChildrens, { autoAlpha: 1, stagger: 0.025 })
      .to(button, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  }, [])

  return (
      <HeaderWrapper className="header" id="main-header">
        <div ref={animWrapper} id="header-logo-wrapper">
          <WhatEver style={{width: '100%'}}/>

          <HeaderButton id="header-button" onClick={() => scrollTo('#poznaj-nas')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowDown} id="header-icon"/>
          </HeaderButton>
        </div>
      </HeaderWrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippet as well where the community can help you? Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial

Yea, this is my repository.
Animations are in header component.

github.com/Zeberko200/whatever-gatsby

Comment: Linking out to a repository keeps this question from being useful for other people in the future. The question should be as self contained as possible so that it retains its usefulness for other people who find in the future after you get your answer.

Comment: Please recreate the issue in a CodeSandbox or StackBlitz project

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to import what you use, for example:

```
import { gsap, TweenMax, TimelineMax, Power2 } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
```

Comment: Nope, I'm using Gatsby V3, not V2 :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for the useful response. My answer is based on an answer provided on github with a similar issue. Lukas take a look at this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8810

Comment: There is no reason to load TweenMax, TimelineMax, or Power2 from GSAP in GSAP 3 unless the user just wants things to be backwards compatible. The OP is not using any GSAP 2 formatting that would require those imports